# Counting occurrences of word in vector

Tags: c++, vector

Say I have a `std::vector<std::string>` with the following content

```
dog
horse
dog
cat
horse
parrot
```

Now I would like to count the no of times each word occurs in the vector.

My first thought is to use the following algorithm this is in rough. I wanted to know if there is a better approach.

```
std::map<std::string , int> map;
for(int i = 0 ; i<vector.size() ; i++)
{
  if(map.find(vector[i] != map.end()
  {
    int c = std::count (vector.begin(), vector.end(), vector[i]);
    map[vector[i]] = c; //The item is not in map add it.
  }
}
```

Comment: `std::map<std::string , int> map; for(const auto & str : vector) map[str]++;`

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the vector?

Comment: Using a std::map is a good approach, but you can do simpler then what you have (as was answered) because the map will create the key value pair and insert it if the key isn't already present.

Comment: Yes I am allowed to sort the vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a map:

```
std::map<std::string , int> histogram;

for (const string & s : v) { ++histogram[s]; }

for (const auto & p : histogram)
{
    std::cout << "Word '" << p.first << "' occurs " << p.second << " times.\n";
}
```

Comment: He is using a map. What he doesn't know is that `histogram[s]++;` will create a new key/value pair with value = 0 and insert it in the map is the key isn't present.

Comment: @FélixCantournet: I meant "can" to be read emphatically, as an affirmation.

Comment: fair enough. Still i think what the OP didn't know was that map operator[] is really smart.

Comment: could you explain '++histogram[s]' ? Does it increment the int value automatically. Could you shed some light

Comment: @MistyD: `histogram[s]` returns the current value in the map with the specified key, inserting a value-constructed element if necessary. `++` increments the value of its operand by one.

Comment: @KerrekSB, are you saying that `histogram[s]` will check to see in the histogram to see if there any others similar keys; if none  add it into the histogram with 1 as its value, but if we have similar keys just keep increment until there is none left ? am i on the right track ? and this was possible because the map does not allow any duplicate right ?

Comment: Not "similar" keys, but *equal* keys according to the comparator predicate. And if there is no such key, a zero-initialized mapped values is added for that key. We turn that zero into a one with the `++` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just increment a counter for each word?

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<vector.size() ; i++)
  map[vector[i]]++;
```

or just

```
for (const auto& i : vector)
  map[i]++;
```

Note that it isn't a great idea to give variables the names of standard library containers.